# mongodb aggregation and sorting on nested array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, group-by, aggregate

Below is my mongo db document structure

```
{
"product_json": {
"productId": 1,
"productData": [
  {
    "productName": "A",
    "productDetails": [
      {
        "manufacturedDate": "2014-08-09",
        "name": "A1",
        "size": 300
      },
      {
        "manufacturedDate": "2012-08-09",
        "name": "A2",
        "size": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productName": "B",
    "productDetails": [
      {
        "manufacturedDate": "2015-08-09",
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 300
      },
      {
        "manufacturedDate": "2017-08-09",
        "name": "B2",
        "size": 200
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
}
```

I need to group by on "manufacturedDate" and apply sorting.Also i dont want the whole document as match.only the matched object(matched productDetails object).

Comment: Try this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$product_json.productData"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$product_json.productData.productDetails"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$product_json.productData.productDetails.manufacturedDate",
      data: {
        $push: "$product_json.productData.productDetails"
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet i have tried it..i need only the matched inner document not the entire document..                                              Matched document should be like below document                                                         
 data :[{
        "manufacturedDate": "2014-08-09",
        "name": "A1",
        "size": 300
      }]

Comment: use `$match` stage after `$unwind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
    {$sort:  {'product_json.productData.productDetails.manufacturedDate': 1}}, 
    { $group:{
      "_id": "$product_json.productData.productDetails.manufacturedDate"
            }
    }
   ]
);
```

Comment: "productData" is inside the "product_json"

Comment: query is working but i need only the matched object not entire document

Comment: @sachin , please tell me , by which field do you want to match

Comment: "productName" and "size"

Comment: @sachin , are you using node js ?

Comment: yes.but i want this in mongodb query only...dont want to loop in node js code

Comment: as you want to match "productName" and "size" , you need to use mongoose find query , .after got matched record , you need to filter record as per your requirement using https://underscorejs.org/ , here no need to use aggregation query.